# Kotlin sorting list without 1 element

Tags: sorting, kotlin

I have a list of objects and I would like to compare them by ids field. However, I would like to item with `id=3` to show first, and then `id=0, id=1` and so on.

`list = list.sortedWith(compareBy<MyItem> {it.id})`

I was trying a lot of combinations but don't know where to add if statement.

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list = list.sortedWith(Comparator { a, b -> when {
    a.id == 3 -> -1
    b.id == 3 -> 1
    else -> Integer.compare(a.id, b.id)
}})
```

Comment: What if _both_ `a` and `b` are 3?